# no operator "<<" matches these operands (variable length arrays)

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm having trouble with a coding assignment in my C++ class. The assignment requires that we have variable length arrays called to functions. I keep getting the error in the title whenever I try to call the function into the main. I've seen other questions similar to this but I can't seem to make the answers that solved any of them work in my own program.

```
    `# include <iostream> //Allows user input
using namespace std;

int i, hold; //Global variables for use in functions and loops through-out the program.
 //Functions below main.

int main()
{
    int length=0;
    int* a = new int[length];; //This array has 'length' spaces.
    cout << "How many numbers would you like to sort?\n";
    cin >> length;
  for(i=0;i<length;i++) //This loop populates the array.
  {
    cout << "Enter a number.\n";
    cin >> a[i];
  }
cout << "This doesn't work ->" << sortDescending(a, length) << endl;
cout << "This also doesn't work" << shiftRight(a, length) << endl;
return 0;
}
```

And here are the functions themselves.

```
    void sortDescending(int a[], int length) //Sorts the numbers in the array in descending order.
{
for(i=0;i<length;i++)
{
    if(a[i]<a[i+1]) //Detects if the first number is smaller than the second.
    { //If the first is smaller than the second then this swaps them.
        hold=a[i];
        a[i]=a[i+1];
        a[i+1]=hold;
    }

}
}

void shiftRight(int a[], int length)
{
for(i=0;i<length;i++)
{
    a[length-i]=a[length-(i-1)];
}
}
```

Comment: You allocate `a` _before_ you get `length`. You need to switch that.

Answer (score 1):

The two functions `sortDescending()` and `shiftRight()` are both `void` returning functions. A function that returns `void` doesn't have a return statement and therefore no value can be obtained from the call. Therefore attempting to "print" the return value of the functions in the following code will invariably fail:

```
... << sortDescending(a, length) << ...
... << shiftRight(a, length)     << ...
```

I'm going to take a step and assume that you're trying to print the actual array. This can be done simply with a for loop after calling the functions:

```
sortDescending(a, length);
std::cout << "After sortDescending(): ";

for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
{
    std::cout << a[i] << " ";
}
std::cout << std::endl;

shiftRight(a, length);
std::cout << "After shiftRight(): ";

// Do the same as the above
```

For further convenience, you can even print the array within the two functions. But that is a task I'll leave up to you. :)

Comment: The prompt actually requires we use those exact headers. They included the void. :/
Any advice on how to get around that?

Comment: @user3427139 I'm not sure what you mean by "exact headers". Also, how does the solution I've shown above not get around it?

Comment: I've added part of the prompt to the OP but in short I'm required to have the functions return void.

Comment: @user3427139 I haven't changed anything about the functions, they still return `void`. This is just a way to print the array *after* calling the two functions.

Comment: Alright, I see where I went wrong with the replies, and fixed that, but now I'm getting this error: "cannot convert parameter 1 from 'int *' to 'int'"

Comment: @user3427139 I don't see where that errors coming from. But I see that `int* a = new int[length];` is creating an array of size `0`. That will make the rest of the code fail also. You need to do the assignment *after* you do `cin >> length;` first.

Comment: @user3427139 Try this code please -- http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6b84288404bb9985

Comment: I think I'm starting to get this now, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a sort function. use algorithm library

```
#include <algorithm>
```

then sort it like this:

```
cout << "This will work" << sort(a, a+length) << endl;
```

Comment: `std::sort()` returns `void` so I don't know what your example code is supposed to accomplish.